# Why can't I pre-select current month on select drop-down element when I can on a year drop-down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using a jquery third party plugin (https://github.com/NickBusey/jQuery-Date-Select-Boxes-Plugin) that pre-populates select elements with year, month, and day. It lists the correct number of days for each month, taking leap year into account.

When the page loads, this script creates the select elements, as expected.

What I want to do after that is pre-select the current month and day so the user doesn't have to always start with January 1.

I have been successful in changing the year, but similar code has no effect on the month and day selects.

Here are the functions for changing the year and the month:

```
function preset_year_select( element ) {
    var year = get_target_year(); // separate function that returns the year
    $(element).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == year;
      }).prop('selected', true);
}

function preset_month_select( element ) {
    var today = new Date();
    var monthname = get_month_name(today); // separate function that returns the month name
    $(element).filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == monthname;
      }).prop('selected', true);
}
```

These selects are in a bootstrap modal. I call these functions when the modal is opened:

```
preset_year_select( $('#pto-entry-form--date-year option') );
preset_month_select( $('#pto-entry-form--date-month option') );
```

I'm getting no errors or anything. I can see that the filter is working on the month if I console.log the output. It will return true on the correct month. It just doesn't set the selected property as the year function does.

Any ideas what I might be missing?